# I cannot figure out how to position my logo and navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I do apologize but I am a beginner and I cannot figure out how to position my logo in the navbar and make everything line up correctly.

I cannot figure out how to make my logo go from [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDZix.jpg) to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0amqJ.jpg)

thank you for your help

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="easychip.html">
            <img src="images/images/chipfixx.png">
        </a>
        <a href="/" id="logo">

        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="easychip.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="easychip-howitworks.html">How it Works</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="easychip-orderpage.html">Order Now</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="easychip-about.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Google+</a>
                            </li </div>
                        </ul>

                    </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<a class="brand" href="easychip.html">
    <img src="images/images/chipfixx.png">
</a>
```

To this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="easychip.html">
    <img src="images/images/chipfixx.png">
</a>
```

I looked at the source code of my own bootstrap website and I'm pretty sure it should work.